# Can existing virtualenv be upgraded gracefully?

Tags: python, virtualenv

I have a virtualenv created for Python 2.5 and want to "upgrade" it to Python 2.6.

Here is how it was originally set up:

```
virtualenv --no-site-packages -p python2.5 myenv
```

I now run virtualenv in the same directory to upgrade:

```
virtualenv --no-site-packages -p python2.6 myenv
...
Not overwriting existing python script myenv/bin/python (you must use myenv/bin/python2.6)
...
Overwriting myenv/bin/activate with new content
```

The default python is still 2.5, even though I can also specify 2.6.  Is there any way to *remove* 2.5 entirely and have 'bin/python' point to 2.6 instead?

Comment: In 2021, I guess the best bet is to just make a new venv and reinstall the dependencies - may other SO answers (including using `upgrade`) may not be apt

Comment: Relevant similar question: [Upgrade Python in a virtual environment](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10218946/364696) that has useful answers for the case of upgrading between bugfix releases (e.g. 3.6.3 to 3.6.7 or the like) in 3.3 and later (there is no good solution beyond saving off requirements and reinstalling them for feature releases).

Answer (score 72, accepted):

You can use the Python 2.6 virtualenv to "revirtual" the existing directory. You will have to reinstall all the modules you installed though. I often have a virtual directory for developing a module, and virtualenv the same directory with many versions of Python, and it works just fine. :)

Comment: Thanks! I tried your method and see that the 'activate' script is updated, but the old version remains (please see the revised question). Are you able to provide an example?

Comment: you can just remove the bin/python executable in the virtualenv before re-running virtualenv with python 2.6.

Comment: Well, you *can* make it work - but why?  The big attraction of `virtualenv` is that it easily and cheaply makes reproducible python environments.  Why muck with one and not be certain you've fixed up everything or that you can reproduce it again or that you're disturbing your production environment when you can just make a new clean one?

Comment: @Wraith: You can just delete bin/python before running virtualenv, or just delete it afterwards and make a new soft-link to bin/python2.6

Comment: @Ned: Virtualenv doesn't make reproducible environments, it makes isolated environments. To reproduce them you need also to install everything the same way, virtualenv isn't enough for that. zc.buildout is better there.

Comment: @Lennart: `Isolated` is indeed a better description.  Even so, the other points still stand.

Comment: @Ned: I agree I wouldn't do this for a production environment, but then I would use buildout for production anyway, and also typically separate compiled Pythons, which makes virtualenv completely superfluous. :)

Comment: @Ned: Point taken; this is a development environment I was working in. I wanted to keep it in 2.5 unless I absolutely needed to do 2.6. That need arose, so I was curious if you could upgrade an isolated environment to see the effects on your code, without having to rebuild and copy/paste directories to the new env.

Comment: You must also remove .Python in the directory. This may be because I'm using virtualenvwrapper

Comment: I don't get it. Could you provide some commands?

Comment: @emeraldhieu Just rerun virtualenv, and then reinstall the packages it had installed.

Answer (score 56):

In Python 3.3+ [venv](https://docs.python.org/3/library/venv.html) supports --upgrade flag

```
  --upgrade             Upgrade the environment directory to use this version
                        of Python, assuming Python has been upgraded in-place.
```

Usage:

```
python -m venv --upgrade YOUR_VENV_DIRECTORY
```

I just upgraded my venv from Python 3.7.x to 3.8 on several projects without any issue.

Comment: "assuming Python has been upgraded in-place" ... this unfortunately seems to mean that if my system `python3` points to 3.6, i can't create get `python3` to point to 3.7 in my venv

Comment: @joel I've not tried it yet, but would `/path/to/user/python -m venv --upgrade` work?

Comment: I don't know if this counts as a graceful upgrade, because it doesn't do anything about the packages installed in the old site-package directory. Thus, since you still need to re-install them it isn't much won in comparison with just recreating the whole virtual environment ...

Comment: Wanted to move my venv from 3.9 to 3.11 (django project) . This command didn't generate any error but  `print(sys.version)`  in a views.py still shows `3.9.14`. Tried with python -m ... python3 -m ... python3.11 -m, with same result. Each time I deactivate + activate my venv. Without success

Comment: Hm... The docs says "Deprecated since version 3.6: pyvenv was the recommended tool..."

Answer (score 4):

You should create a new `virtualenv` using `python2.6` and then, after activating the new env, use its `python2.6` and its `easy_install` to install new versions of any site packages you need.  Beware that the path name to the `virtualenv` is hardwired into various files within the environment, so, when you are ready to switch over to it, either change your startup scripts et al to refer to the new `virualenv` path or be very careful about copying it over to the old directory and modifying the path names inside it.

Answer (score 4):

You can simply do this by go to your venv file and change the python path and it's version from pyvenv.cfg like this:

[image]

Comment: Try not to paste images if its not necessary. The details in the answer should be entered as text

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/33500184)

Answer (score 2):

Install a second Python on CentOS

1. download python
2. install to diff local

   ```
   configure --prefix=/opt/virtualenv/python 
   make && make install
   ```
3. create virtual env using new python

   ```
   virtualenv /opt/virtualenv --python=/opt/python276/bin/python
   ```

   note: if needed it can be done with a different user

   ```
   chown pyuser -R /opt/virtualenv
   su - pyuser
   source /opt/virtualenv/bin/activate
   python -v
   ```
4. Create virtual env:

   ```
   virtualenv /opt/virtualenv
   su - infograficos
   source bin/activate
   ```
5. Install pip with python 2.7 (inside virtualenv)

   ```
   easy_install pip
   ```

Answer (score 0):

If you're using OS X, try [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24724360/2293304) if you want to upgrade Python to a minor-increased version (e.g. 2.7.6 to 2.7.8) while keeping third-party libraries work.

It work for me on 5 different virtual environments with Django installed.