# urllib2 retrieving html with Â and &amp; symbols/letters now and again, unsure how to remove them

Tags: python, python-2.7, character-encoding, beautifulsoup, urllib2

I'm trying to get the html of a page using urllib2 and parsing it through beautifulsoup but I have hit a problem with the html having `Â` and `&amp` symbols/letters everywhere for example here is a code snippit:

`<p>Total&amp;2 Â£100.00.<br/>Total&amp;2 Â£100.00<br/>Total&amp;2 Â£100.00</p>`

I am unable to remove the `Â` using strip or replace...

The bit of code getting the html is:

```
html = urllib2.urlopen("http://www.websitehere.com", timeout=10).read().decode('UTF-8')
soup = BeautifulSoup(html)
```

Anyone able to help?

**EDIT**

I've tried various decodings and also tried everything located in: [How to make the python interpreter correctly handle non-ASCII characters in string operations?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1342000/how-to-replace-non-ascii-characters-in-string) but still nothing :/

Thanks
- Hyflex

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have a suspicion that this is related the the parser that BS will use to read the HTML.  They [document it here](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#installing-a-parser) but if you're like me (on OSX) you might be stuck with something that requires a bit of work:

You'll notice that in the BS4 documentation page above, they point out that by default BS4 will use the Python built-in HTML parser.  Assuming you are in OSX, the Apple-bundled version of Python is 2.7.2 which is not lenient for character formatting.  I hit this same problem, so I upgraded by version of Python to work around it.  Doing this in a virtualenv will minimize disruption to other projects.

If doing that sounds like a pain, you can switch over to the LXML parser:

```
pip install lxml
```

And then try:

```
soup = BeautifulSoup(html, "lxml")
```

Depending on your scenario, that might be good enough.  I found this annoying enough to warrant upgrading my version of Python.  Using virtualenv, [you can migrate your packages](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2170252/can-existing-virtualenv-be-upgraded-gracefully) fairly easily

Comment: Looks like Mavericks updates Python to 2.7.5, so that is another option for local development.