# bs4.FeatureNotFound: Couldn't find a tree builder with the features you requested: lxml. Do you need to install a parser library?

Tags: python, python-2.7, beautifulsoup, lxml

```
...
soup = BeautifulSoup(html, "lxml")
File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/bs4/__init__.py", line 152, in __init__
% ",".join(features))
bs4.FeatureNotFound: Couldn't find a tree builder with the features you requested: lxml. Do you need to install a parser library?
```

The above outputs on my Terminal. I am on Mac OS 10.7.x. I have Python 2.7.1, and followed [this tutorial](http://www.gregreda.com/2013/03/03/web-scraping-101-with-python/) to get Beautiful Soup and lxml, which both installed successfully and work with a separate test file [located here](http://web.engr.illinois.edu/%7Eshauk2/testWebScrape.py). In the Python script that causes this error, I have included this line:
`from pageCrawler import comparePages`
And in the pageCrawler file I have included the following two lines:
`from bs4 import BeautifulSoup`
`from urllib2 import urlopen`

How can this problem be solved?

Comment: see this answer - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17766725/how-to-re-install-lxml

Comment: Is `html` a url or a the html contents?

Answer (score 459):

I have a suspicion that this is related to the parser that BS will use to read the HTML.  They [document is here](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#installing-a-parser), but if you're like me (on OSX) you might be stuck with something that requires a bit of work:

You'll notice that in the BS4 documentation page above, they point out that by default BS4 will use the Python built-in HTML parser.  Assuming you are in OSX, the Apple-bundled version of Python is 2.7.2 which is not lenient for character formatting.  I hit this same problem, so I upgraded my version of Python to work around it. Doing this in a virtualenv will minimize disruption to other projects.

If doing that sounds like a pain, you can switch over to the LXML parser:

```
pip install lxml
```

And then try:

```
soup = BeautifulSoup(html, "lxml")
```

Depending on your scenario, that might be good enough.  I found this annoying enough to warrant upgrading my version of Python.  Using virtualenv, [you can migrate your packages](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2170252/can-existing-virtualenv-be-upgraded-gracefully) fairly easily.

Comment: To test after pip install : `python -c 'import requests ; from bs4 import BeautifulSoup ; r = requests.get("https://www.allrecipes.com/recipes/96/salad/") ; soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text, "lxml") '`

Comment: in my virtual env, I needed to install `requests`, `bs4` and `lxml` before `BeautifulSoup` would parse my webpage content.

Comment: Uff! Mad Mac, I dont know when I'll stop regretting my decision of buying Mac!

Comment: The first time I had to run lxml I added the line `import lxml` into my script then it ran

Comment: This didn't work for me on my MacAir MacOS 14.3 (Sonoma), M2 Chip using JupyterLab.

Wound up having to do:
`import html5lib`

Then:
`soup = BeautifulSoup(c, "html5lib")`

as suggested by Tim Seed below.

Answer (score 119):

I'd prefer the built in python html parser, no install no dependencies

`soup = BeautifulSoup(s,  "html.parser")`

Comment: Although this answer doesn't answer question directly, it does provide potentially a better alternative. I had no preference for xlml and i changed everything to html.parser and it worked. I'd rather carry forward with something that works out of the box , than drag on the unnecessary technical debt.

Comment: Sometimes the html parser doesn't do the job. Some page requires the XML parser to do the job.

Comment: `html.parser` does not preserve the case for XML elements and makes them all lowercase. :(

Answer (score 65):

For basic out of the box python with bs4 installed then you can process your xml with

```
soup = BeautifulSoup(html, "html5lib")
```

If however you want to use **formatter='xml'** then you need to

```
pip3 install lxml

soup = BeautifulSoup(html, features="xml")
```

Comment: On a newly spun up remote server, html5lib didn't work out of the box for me. I still had to do a ```pip install html5lib```, after which everything worked fine.

Comment: Didn't work for me: `bs4.FeatureNotFound: Couldn't find a tree builder with the features you requested: html5lib. Do you need to install a parser library?` If I change it to `html.parser` it works

Answer (score 61):

Run these three commands to make sure that you have all the relevant packages installed:

```
pip install bs4
pip install html5lib
pip install lxml
```

Then restart your Python IDE, if needed.

That should take care of anything related to this issue.

Comment: This is the actual solution.

Comment: The key for me on this was restarting the IDE that triggered this all to work successfully

Comment: This is what we call a solution.

Answer (score 49):

Actually 3 of the options mentioned by other work.

```py
# 1. 
soup_object= BeautifulSoup(markup,"html.parser") #Python HTML parser

# 2. 
pip install lxml
soup_object= BeautifulSoup(markup,'lxml') # C dependent parser 

# 3.
pip install html5lib
soup_object= BeautifulSoup(markup,'html5lib') # C dependent parser
```

Comment: In my case `lxml` used to work but when I switched to `html.parser` it froze.

Answer (score 19):

I am using **Python 3.6** and I had the same original error in this post. After I ran the command:

```
python3 -m pip install lxml
```

it resolved my problem

Comment: In Docker it's also necessary to `apt install python-lxml`

Comment: I don't need to run `apt install python-lxml`, but perhaps this is image-dependent. It suffices for me to do `python3 -m pip install lxml`.

Answer (score 18):

Install LXML parser in python environment.

```
pip install lxml
```

Your problem will be resolve. You can also use built-in python package for the same as:

```
soup = BeautifulSoup(s,  "html.parser")
```

Note: The "HTMLParser" module has been renamed to "html.parser" in Python3

Answer (score 14):

Instead of using lxml use html.parser, you can use this piece of code:

```
soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'html.parser')
```

Comment: `vendor.bs.bs4.FeatureNotFound: Couldn't find a tree builder with the features you requested: html.parser. Do you need to install a parser library?`

Answer (score 8):

Although BeautifulSoup supports the HTML parser by default
If you want to use any other third-party Python parsers you need to install that external parser like(lxml).

```
soup_object= BeautifulSoup(markup, "html.parser") #Python HTML parser
```

But if you don't specified any parser as parameter  you will get an warning that no parser specified.

```
soup_object= BeautifulSoup(markup) #Warnning
```

To use any other external parser you need to install it and then need to specify it. like

```
pip install lxml

soup_object= BeautifulSoup(markup, 'lxml') # C dependent parser
```

External parser have c and python dependency which may have some advantage and disadvantage.

Answer (score 6):

`pip install lxml` then keeping `xml` in `soup = BeautifulSoup(URL, "xml")` did the job on Mac.

Answer (score 5):

In my case I had an outdated version of the `lxml` package. So I just updated it and this fixed the issue.

```
sudo python3 -m pip install lxml --upgrade
```

Comment: thank you! this is what I needed to do also

Answer (score 3):

I encountered the same issue. I found the reason is that I had a slightly-outdated python six package.

```
>>> import html5lib
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/html5lib/__init__.py", line 16, in <module>
    from .html5parser import HTMLParser, parse, parseFragment
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/html5lib/html5parser.py", line 2, in <module>
    from six import with_metaclass, viewkeys, PY3
ImportError: cannot import name viewkeys
```

Upgrading your six package will solve the issue:

```
sudo pip install six=1.10.0
```

Comment: `sudo pip install six==1.10.0`

Answer (score 2):

BS4 by default expects an HTML document. Therefore, it parses an XML document as an HTML one. Pass `features="xml"` as an argument in the constructor. It resolved my issue.

Comment: you need to install `lxml`, with `pip install lxml`

Answer (score 1):

In some references, use the second instead of the first:

```
soup_object= BeautifulSoup(markup,'html-parser')
soup_object= BeautifulSoup(markup,'html.parser')
```

Comment: You should provide a bit more detail in your answer

Answer (score 1):

The error is coming because of the parser you are using. In general, if you have HTML file/code then you need to use `html5lib`(documentation can be found [here](https://github.com/html5lib/html5lib-python#html5lib)) & in-case you have XML file/data then you need to use `lxml`(documentation can be found [here](https://lxml.de/4.4/lxmldoc-4.4.2.pdf)). You can use `lxml` for HTML file/code also but sometimes it gives an error as above. So, better to choose the package wisely based on the type of data/file. You can also use `html_parser` which is built-in module. But, this also sometimes do not work.

For more details regarding when to use which package you can see the details [here](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#installing-a-parser)

Answer (score 1):

Blank parameter will result in a warning for best available.
soup = BeautifulSoup(html)

---------------/UserWarning: No parser was explicitly specified, so I'm using the best available HTML parser for this system ("html5lib"). This usually isn't a problem, but if you run this code on another system, or in a different virtual environment, it may use a different parser and behave differently.----------------------/

python --version  Python 3.7.7

PyCharm 19.3.4 CE

Answer (score 1):

My solution was to remove `lxml` from conda and reinstalling it with pip.

Answer (score 1):

I am using python 3.8 in pycharm. I assume that you had not installed "lxml" before you started working. This is what I did:

---

1. Go to File -> Settings
2. Select " Python Interpreter " on the left menu bar of settings, select "Python Interpreter."
3. Click the "+" icon over the list of packages.
4. Search for "lxml."
5. Click "Install Package" on the bottom left of the "Available Package" window.

Answer (score 1):

I fixed with below changes

Before changes

```
soup = BeautifulSoup(r.content, 'html5lib' )
print (soup.prettify())
```

After change

```
soup = BeautifulSoup(r.content, features='html')
print(soup.prettify())
```

my code works properly

Comment: Are you sure of the syntax? The string in the second block of code doesn't seem to be valid Python syntax

Comment: Nowi it is work

Answer (score 1):

You may want to double check that you're using the right interpreter if you have multiple versions of Python installed.

Once I chose the correct version of Python, lxml was found.

Answer (score 1):

Important for Jupyternotebook-Users: If you decide for the lxml parser make sure to restart the jupyternotebook kernel after installing it with `pip install lxml`. Otherwise the parser can not be found as it is not yet inititalized properly. Restarting the kernel is possible via the jupyternotebook web/pycharm/vscode GUI.

Answer (score 0):

This method worked for me. I prefer to mention that I was trying this in the virtual environment. First:

```
pip install --upgrade bs4
```

Secondly, I used:

```
html.parser
```

instead of

```
html5lib
```