# bs4.FeatureNotFound: Couldn't find a tree builder with the features you requested: html5lib

Tags: python, python-3.x, beautifulsoup, html5lib

I got this error when running my python code:

```
bs4.FeatureNotFound: Couldn't find a tree builder with the features you requested: html5lib. Do you need to install a parser library?
```

So I searched online and read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24398302/bs4-featurenotfound-couldnt-find-a-tree-builder-with-the-features-you-requeste)

I checked my packages installed, both html5lib and six seem to be the latest version.

```
beautifulsoup4 (4.6.0)
html5lib (1.0.1)
pip (9.0.1)
setuptools (28.8.0)
six (1.11.0)
webencodings (0.5.1)
```

I wonder what is the problem here?

*The context:

```
import urllib.request
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url0 = 'http://py4e-data.dr-chuck.net/known_by_Cruz.html'

url = url0
name = list()
for i in range(0,7):
    html = urllib.request.urlopen(url).read()
    soup = BeautifulSoup(html,"html5lib")
....
```

When I ran the exact same code in jupyter notebook it ran without problem.

Answer (score 4):

Try to replace `"html5lib"` with `"html.parser"`

For example:

`soup = BeautifulSoup(html,"html5lib")` **->** `soup = BeautifulSoup(data, "html.parser")`