# Couldn't find a tree builder with the features you requested: html5lib. Do you need to install a parser library?

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I try to use soup4 with my python3.5 ,but evrey time i rule a code to extrac something from internet i get this error :

```
 - s4\__init__.py", line 198, in __init__
       % ",".join(features)) bs4.FeatureNotFound: Couldn't find a tree builder with the features you requested: html5lib. Do you need to    install a parser library?
```

There was a link with the same error in this site [bs4.FeatureNotFound: Couldn't find a tree builder with the features you requested: lxml. Do you need to install a parser library?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24398302/bs4-featurenotfound-couldnt-find-a-tree-builder-with-the-features-you-requeste)
I tried all , still get the error

All the pip install requests 
pip install lxml
pip install beautifull soup4

I download soup4 https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/download/4.6/ manual an install it   setup.py install

I have all updated and working , but still i get the error plz help me

Comment: whats your code that giving this error?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

If you are using `html5lib` as an underlying parser:

```
soup = BeautifulSoup(html, "html5lib")
#                            ^HERE^
```

Then, you need to have `html5lib` module installed in your python environment:

```
pip install html5lib
```

Documentation reference: [Installing a parser](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#installing-a-parser).

Answer (score 3):

For those that get the same error even with html5lib installed, replace "html5lib" for "html.parser" as suggested in https://github.com/coursera-dl/edx-dl/issues/434

Worked for me :)

Answer (score 1):

Use '**html.parser**' instead of '**html5lib**'. This will work.

Answer (score 0):

For me html.parser work

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import urllib.request 
response = urllib.request.urlopen('http://php.net/') 
html = response.read()
soup = BeautifulSoup(html,"html.parser")
text = soup.get_text(strip=True)
print (text)
```