# Errors trying to switch to new version of Python in Visual Studio Code

Tags: python, visual-studio-code

I am using visual studio code to run a program in python. I wrote my program in python 3.7 and everything was fine. I tried to install jupyterlab but it needed a new version. So I switched to Python 3.11 (3.11.0 64-bit to be more precise).

When I run my code in the newer Python version it says:

> bs4.FeatureNotFound: Couldn't find a tree builder with the features you requested: lxml. Do you need to install a parser library?

For line: `soup = BeautifulSoup(page,features="lxml")`

According to a 2018 topic [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53787102/couldnt-find-a-tree-builder-with-the-features-you-requested-html5lib-do-you-n), where the user has the same problem, the most upvoted and accepted answer suggests to do two things. To add `"html5lib"` and pip install `html5lib`. I do the hypothesis that I need to do the same about `lxml`.

That's why I run `pip install lxml`. Now it returns:

```
error: subprocess-exited-with-error

  × Running setup.py install for lxml did not run successfully.       
  │ exit code: 1
  ╰─> [96 lines of output]
      Building lxml version 4.9.1.
      Building without Cython.
      Building against pre-built libxml2 andl libxslt libraries       
      running install
```

And a [screenshot](https://prnt.sc/6lMlkeneYIuH). And at the end again:

```
      *********************************************************************************
      Could not find function xmlCheckVersion in library libxml2. Is libxml2 installed?
      *********************************************************************************
      [end of output]

  note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
error: legacy-install-failure

× Encountered error while trying to install package.
╰─> lxml

note: This is an issue with the package mentioned above, not pip.
hint: See above for output from the failure.
```

And a [screenshot](https://prnt.sc/vKlR-bDSE09x). In [this Stackoverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74332756/installing-lxml-facing-a-legacy-install-failure-error) they suggest to go back a version which sounds like a bad idea. And I do not know if the libraries I want to install will be available there. (In addition, there is no accepted answer and some answers even say to reinstall the entire OS?!)

Then I checked [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71152710/failing-to-install-lxml-using-pip) and I tried to install `pip install C:\Users\@@@@@\Downloads\lxml-4.9.1-cp311-cp311-win_amd64.whl`. While everything is there as I downloaded them ([screenshot](https://prnt.sc/GprdwvVUnhOP) of the folder), it returns an error:

```
ERROR: Could not install packages due to an OSError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'C:\\Users\\@@@@@\\Downloads\\lxml-4.9.1-cp311-cp311-win_amd64.whl'
```

Information that may be needed:

- Windows 10
- Visual Studio Code Version 1.74.0
- Chosen Interpreter 3.11.0 https://prnt.sc/5N4w8srPSZ25

Comment: https://beautiful-soup-4.readthedocs.io/en/latest/#installing-a-parser

Comment: @It_is_Chris I have read the documentation. I have installed both the beautifulsoup4 and html5lib. The "Problems after installation" sections does not include my errors. Neither does "Troubleshooting" section.

Answer (score 0):

> Could not find function xmlCheckVersion in library libxml2. Is libxml2 installed?

You can install lxml for your python 3.11 from [https://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#lxml](https://www.lfd.uci.edu/%7Egohlke/pythonlibs/#lxml). And I suggest [lxml‑4.9.0‑cp311‑cp311‑win_amd64.whl](https://javascript:;).

After you downloading it, you can use following command to install it:

```
pip install C:\path\to\downloaded\file\lxml‑4.9.0‑cp311‑cp311‑win_amd64.whl
```