# "bs4.FeatureNotFound: Couldn't find a tree builder with the features you requested: lxml" after installing lxml

Tags: python, beautifulsoup, pip, lxml

I'm trying to use Beautiful Soup to parse an XML document. Here's the code where I instantiate a `BeautifulSoup` object:

```
with open(filename, encoding='utf-8') as f_:
    content = f_.read()
xml_cont = BeautifulSoup(content, 'lxml')
```

When I ran my code I received the following error:

```
  File "[omitted]", line 13, in [omitted]
    xml_cont = BeautifulSoup(content, 'lxml')
  File "/Users/Josh/Library/Python/3.7/lib/python/site-packages/bs4/__init__.py", line 228, in __init__
    % ",".join(features))
bs4.FeatureNotFound: Couldn't find a tree builder with the features you requested: lxml. Do you need to install a parser library?
```

I did a quick search and [saw](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24398302/bs4-featurenotfound-couldnt-find-a-tree-builder-with-the-features-you-requeste?rq=1) that I needed to install `lxml` with pip. I did so.

```
pip3 install lxml
```

However, **I am still getting the error!** Any ideas as to why?

Comment: Try `xml_cont = BeautifulSoup(content, features="xml")`, and inform the result.

Comment: @F.NiX tried this, got the same result

Comment: What about `xml_cont = BeautifulSoup(content, "html5lib")`?

Answer (score 2):

I have tried many libraries with pip, but didn't work for me.It only worked when I have installed the library from the IDE (Pycharm).

with open(file name) as file:
soup = BeautifulSoup(file, "lxml")

[lxml library install](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1DPOm.png)