# How to solve Selenium exception: " invalid argument 'url' must be a string "

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

I'm trying to use the insta-scrape library for python, specifically the method to get all posts of a instagram profile.

This is the link to the library page:
https://pypi.org/project/insta-scrape/

This is the link to the library doc in particular for the method get_posts:
https://instascrape.readthedocs.io/en/latest/instascrape.scrapers.html#module-instascrape.scrapers.profile

My simple code is :

```
options = Options()
options.add_argument('--headless')
driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=options)
insta_profile = Profile('https://www.instagram.com/molteni_matteo/')
insta_profile.scrape()
list_post = insta_profile.get_posts(webdriver=driver, amount=None,
                                      login_first=False, login_pause=60,
                                      max_failed_scroll=300, scrape=False, scrape_pause=5)
for profile_post in list_post:
    print(profile_post)
```

But it gives me the error :

[image: error]

How can i solve this problem ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's actually a bug in the python module, where Profile doesn't accept the url correctly.
You can fix it by setting

`insta_profile.url = 'https://www.instagram.com/molteni_matteo/'`

before calling `get_posts`

Comment: Thanks mate. Had this issue but I get the following error:
`bs4.FeatureNotFound: Couldn't find a tree builder with the features you requested: lxml. Do you need to install a parser library?`

Comment: You probably do need to install a parser library.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24398302/bs4-featurenotfound-couldnt-find-a-tree-builder-with-the-features-you-requeste