# upgrade virtualenv python 3 to 3.4.3

Tags: python, python-3.x, virtualenv

Is there a way to upgrade e.g. python 3.4.1 to 3.4.3 on my virtualenv? I can't see and google results teaching to upgrade from pythong 3.x to 3.+x

Thanks!

EDIT: I have to emphasize that i am talking about upgrading my virtualenv's python 3 to a more recent version, not upgrading python 2.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Can existing virtualenv be upgraded gracefully?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2170252/can-existing-virtualenv-be-upgraded-gracefully)

Comment: It's better to create a new virtualenv, it's intended to be thrown away and rebuilt.

Comment: just run `python3.4.3 -mvirtualenv /path/to/your-virtualenv` if you don't want to recreate it from scratch.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have fixed this by just installing a more recent version of Python 3 (Python 3.4.3 to be exact). My virtualenvs running Python 3.4.1 seemed to have upgraded by themselves.